# Jest 28 and React: Module imports without file extensions are not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've been trying to upgrade jest on my project using the migration guide https://jestjs.io/ro/docs/upgrading-to-jest28
Everything works ok, except for module imports. If the file extension is not specified, I get an error when trying to run the tests

[image]

If I specify also the file extension, tests run well.

I checked the jest documentation and I already have the moduleFileExtensions correctly set moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],

This did not happen in Jest 27

```
module.exports = {
collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!**/*.d.ts'],
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ignorePatterns,
setupFiles: [require.resolve('../polyfills')],
setupFilesAfterEnv: [require.resolve('./setupTests'), userSetupFile].filter(Boolean),
testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '<rootDir>/**/*.+(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '<rootDir>/**/*-specs.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
],
testPathIgnorePatterns: ignorePatterns,
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
testEnvironmentOptions: {pretendToBeVisual: true},
testURL: 'http://localhost',
transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': require.resolve('./babelTransform'),
    '^.+\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': require.resolve('./cssTransform.js'),
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|less|sass|scss|json)$)': require.resolve('./fileTransform')
},
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$'
],
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': require.resolve('identity-obj-proxy'),
    '^@testing-library/jest-dom$': require.resolve('@testing-library/jest-dom'),
    '^@testing-library/react$': require.resolve('@testing-library/react'),
    '^@testing-library/user-event$': require.resolve('@testing-library/user-event'),
    '^react$': require.resolve('react'),
},
moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
globals,
watchPlugins: ['jest-watch-typeahead/filename', 'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'].map(m => require.resolve(m)),
resetMocks: true
```

FileTransform.js:

```
module.exports = {
process(src, filename) {
    const assetFilename = JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename));
    return `module.exports = ${assetFilename};`;
}
```

};

Comment: can you provide your, jest.config.js  configuration?

Comment: i edited the main question

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani i answered your question

Comment: @DanielStoian were you able to find out what the issue is?

Comment: @EduardVoiculescu, i changed a bit the fileTransform code, but also I only did it after jest 29 was released.  And it worked. I will answer my question below

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit the code in fileTransform.js and it seems to be working. But now I am using jest 29

[image: fileTransform.js]